# Registering failed attempt inside checked function seems to be counted double

Tags: circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I'm exploring resilience4j and would like to both be able to record a failure for a circuit breaker inside a checked function, as well as returning a meaningful result. But the failure seems to be counted double when I do.

I'm using version 0.13.1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Check the following test, we have a closed ring buffer of 10 which indicates that 10 calls should be evaluated before the CircuitBreaker can be tripped open. This is the case except when recording a failure with the circuitbreaker's `onError` method inside a checked function:

```java
@Test
public void testRecordFailure() {
    CircuitBreakerConfig config = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
        .ringBufferSizeInClosedState(10)
        .build();

    CircuitBreakerRegistry registry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(config);

    CircuitBreaker breaker1 = registry.circuitBreaker("breaker-1");

    CircuitBreaker breaker2 = registry.circuitBreaker("breaker-2");
    CheckedFunction0<String> supplier2 = CircuitBreaker.decorateCheckedSupplier(breaker2, () -> {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    });

    CircuitBreaker breaker3 = registry.circuitBreaker("breaker-3");
    CheckedFunction0<String> supplier3 = CircuitBreaker.decorateCheckedSupplier(breaker3, () -> {
        breaker3.onError(0, new RuntimeException());
        return "meaningful-result";
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        breaker1.onError(0, new RuntimeException());
        Try.of(supplier2);
        Try.of(supplier3);
    }

    assertEquals(CircuitBreaker.State.CLOSED, breaker1.getState()); // Success
    assertEquals(CircuitBreaker.State.CLOSED, breaker2.getState()); // Success
    assertEquals(CircuitBreaker.State.CLOSED, breaker3.getState()); // Success

    breaker1.onError(0, new RuntimeException());
    Try.of(supplier2);
    Try.of(supplier3);

    assertEquals(CircuitBreaker.State.CLOSED, breaker1.getState()); // Success
    assertEquals(CircuitBreaker.State.CLOSED, breaker2.getState()); // Success
    assertEquals(CircuitBreaker.State.CLOSED, breaker3.getState()); // Failure - circuit is now OPEN - why?
}
```

I've not been able to find an explanation for this behaviour, or if there it exists a way to record a failure for a circuit breaker inside a checked function. Can anybody shed some light on this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to invoke onError. It's done by the higher order function.